# Did the events at the Tower of Babel occur?

Tags: christianity, bible

What is Islam's view of the Tower of Babel? Is it in/compatible with the Quran? Is there a belief in Islam that takes the place of the Tower of Babel?

Comment: I don't think that Towers of Babel are directly mentioned in Quran. If you have any reference, please add it in question

Answer (score 3):

There are references to a similar attempt by Pharaoh of Egypt in Sura Qasas and Sura Ghafir of the Holy Quran.

In Sura Qisas:

> Pharaoh said, “O nobles, I know of no god for you other than me. So
>   fire-up the bricks for me O Hamaan, and build me a tower, that I may
>   ascend to the God of Moses, though I think he is a liar.” (28:38)

In Sura Ghafir:

> And Pharaoh said, “O Hamaan, build me a tower, that I may reach the
>   pathways. (40:36) The pathways of the heavens, so that I may glance at
>   the God of Moses; though I think he is lying.” Thus Pharaoh’s evil
>   deeds were made to appear good to him, and he was averted from the
>   path. Pharaoh's guile was only in defeat. (40:37)

Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Babel#Islamic_tradition) traces possible allusions to the story in other Islamic sources.